# Broadcom 4315 stop working after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: wireless, 12.04, broadcom

lspci -n | grep 14e4

```
02:00.0 0280: 14e4:4315 (rev 01)
```

lspci -vvv

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- [disabled] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: i915 Kernel modules: i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR-
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3073 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode]) Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn- Capabilities:
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: ahci
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1508 Physical Slot: 1 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx- Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- Kernel modules: ssb
85:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3072 Physical Slot: 5 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+ Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- Kernel driver in use: sky2 Kernel modules: sky2
```

lsmod

```
Module Size Used by rfcomm 38139 0 bnep 17830 2 bluetooth 158438 10 rfcomm,bnep parport_pc 32114 0 ppdev 12849 0 binfmt_misc 17292 1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi 31775 1 snd_hda_codec_analog 75395 1 hp_wmi 13652 0 sparse_keymap 13658 1 hp_wmi ip6t_LOG 16846 4 xt_hl 12465 6 ip6t_rt 12473 3 nf_conntrack_ipv6 13581 7 nf_defrag_ipv6 13139 1 nf_conntrack_ipv6 ipt_REJECT 12512 1 ipt_LOG 12783 5 joydev 17393 0 xt_limit 12541 12 xt_tcpudp 12531 22 xt_addrtype 12596 4 xt_state 12514 14 snd_hda_intel 32765 3 snd_hda_codec 109562 3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel snd_hwdep 13276 1 snd_hda_codec snd_pcm 80845 3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec uvcvideo 67203 0 ip6table_filter 12711 1 videodev 86588 1 uvcvideo ip6_tables 22528 3 ip6t_LOG,ip6t_rt,ip6table_filter nf_conntrack_netbios_ns 12585 0 nf_conntrack_broadcast 12541 1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_nat_ftp 12595 0 nf_nat 24959 1 nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ipv4 19084 9 nf_nat nf_defrag_ipv4 12649 1 nf_conntrack_ipv4 snd_seq_midi 13132 0 nf_conntrack_ftp 13183 1 nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack 73847 8 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp iptable_filter 12706 1 snd_rawmidi 25424 1 snd_seq_midi ip_tables 18106 1 iptable_filter x_tables 21974 13 ip6t_LOG,xt_hl,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ipt_LOG,xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables snd_seq_midi_event 14475 1 snd_seq_midi snd_seq 51567 2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event snd_timer 28931 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq psmouse 72846 0 snd_seq_device 14172 3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq serio_raw 13027 0 snd 62064 16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device soundcore 14635 1 snd snd_page_alloc 14108 2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm hp_accel 25728 0 lis3lv02d 19268 1 hp_accel input_polldev 13648 1 lis3lv02d i915 414603 3 drm_kms_helper 45466 1 i915 drm 197692 4 i915,drm_kms_helper wmi 18744 1 hp_wmi mac_hid 13077 0 i2c_algo_bit 13199 1 i915 video 19068 1 i915 lp 17455 0 parport 40930 3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp usbhid 41906 0 hid 77367 1 usbhid sky2 53628 0
```

ifconfig -a

```
eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:a9:05:cb:4d:21
inet addr:192.168.0.14 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::1aa9:5ff:fecb:4d21/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:6353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:6371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:5005147 (5.0 MB) TX bytes:971681 (971.6 KB) Interrupt:17
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:1092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:146272 (146.2 KB) TX bytes:146272 (146.2 KB)
```

iwconfig

```
lo no wireless extensions.
eth1 no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: please add the output of `sudo lshw -class network` and `rfkill list all` to your question.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to 12.04 Ubuntu and I have this problem. This is my `rfkill list all` output:

```
shirish@shirish-Inspiron-1545:~$ rfkill list all
0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: yes
  Hard blocked: yes
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: yes
  Hard blocked: yes
```

What should I do now? I tried the `rfkill unblock all` but it does not work.

Comment: You should have a switch around your computer somewhere, for that's what _Hard blocked_ stands for: Blocked hardware-wise. What is the make and model of your computer?